# image in updatepanel causes whole page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, updatepanel

i have an image control inside update panel, in the page load i am setting its url.

code behind in page_load

```
string url = "example.com";
Image1.ImageUrl = url;
```

inside updatepanel in aspx

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" CssClass="image" />
```

i also have couple of submit buttons inside the updatepanel, and i am updating some texboxes and labels on button clicks.

however this causes whole page to refresh. (the scrollbar goes up.)

if move the image outside of update panel this doesn't happen. 
the problem is the layout doesn't work at all if i remove the image outside of updatepanel.
can anyone help me with this? thanks.

**UPDATE**

i have realized this only happens in Chrome. Does anyone have an idea ?

**UPDATE 2**
On that page I have resolved the issue by removing the img from the updatepanel. It was hell to get the layout work, but it worked.

However I have another page, where I am adding new imgs to the updatepanel when a user clicks load more. Same deal, and obviously i can't move image out of update panel this time. Here is the code.

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

        <!--Recent Uploads-->
        <div class="uploads">
            <h2>Uploads</h2>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="RecentUpload" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="loaduploads"/>
                </Triggers>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button CssClass="uploadButton" ID="loaduploads" runat="server" Text="Load More" OnClick="loaduploads_Click" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
```

Code behind (upload index is a session variable)

```
upload_index += 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < upload_index; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                SSImage img = images[i];
                HyperLink imglink = new HyperLink();
                imglink.NavigateUrl = "/Image.aspx?id=" + img.id;
                imglink.ImageUrl = "/ShowImage.ashx?imgid=" + img.id;
                imglink.ToolTip = img.title;
                imglink.CssClass = "imgupload";
                Control contentpanel = RecentUpload.ContentTemplateContainer;
                contentpanel.Controls.AddAt(contentpanel.Controls.Count - 2, imglink);
            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
            {
                loaduploads.Visible = false;
                break;
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE 3**

the problem does not happen with static images, rather happens when i am trying to load from `showimage.ashx`. here is the code.

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="ShowImage" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public class ShowImage : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        try
        {
            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);

            cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Image_data FROM [Image_table] WHERE Image_id = " + context.Request.QueryString["imgID"], conn);
            conn.Open();
            Object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            //if nothing found throw exception
            if (result == null)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
                context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])rdr["Image_data"]);
            }

            if (rdr != null)
                rdr.Close();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }

    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you put `Triggers` in your Update Panel ?

Comment: @zey yes i have `asyncpostbacktrigger`

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: @zey the whole thing?

Comment: `UpdatePanel` with `asyncpostbacktrigger` :)

Comment: @zey i have updated the question and put the code. the code works fine in firefox and ie9 (didnt test with 10). but seems to do a complete postback in chrome.

Comment: I feel like I have seen this problem before...few ideas: 1) is the markup generated valid HTML? and 2) what does the HTTP conversation look like between browser/server (viewed in the Chrome dev tools)? Perhaps there is a clue there. 3) I would also attach the script debugger and look for any non-fatal errors.

Comment: @TimMedora in the network tab, when i click the button, there is a post and bunch get's for images. initiator is ScriptResource.axd

Comment: @TimMedora there are some warnings about fonts on script console but thats on all pages, other than that nothing

Comment: How about if you run the whole page source through validator.w3.org? sometimes a structural error can confuse the browser (and browsers deal with errors in different ways).

Comment: @TimMedora i have two errors on validator for `An img element must have an alt attribute.` nothing important.

Comment: Got it...are you able to reproduce the problem with a stripped down version of the page? (just the minimum code required to make it work with everything else removed).

Comment: @TimMedora i will try and get back to you.

Comment: @TimMedora yep i have stripped down everything. just a loadbutton and on button click i am loading images into updatepanel. doesnt work on chrome.

Comment: I'm out of ideas...if you are able to zip up a self-contained version of the project, I'll download and try it on my machine.

Comment: @TimMedora i have created a new project to test this again. and now i can't recreate it. i will look deeper.

Comment: @TimMedora i updated the question please take a look. basically the problem doesnt happen with static images, rather happens with images that i load from database particularly from showimage.ashx.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your latest update. I created a test setup with an image served from an ASHX inside an `UpdatePanel`, but I couldn't get it to break in IE10 or Chrome 26. I tried serving valid images and also throwing an exception from the handler.

Comment: By Static images it works.. does it means that Logic in the button click as `imglink.ImageUrl = "/ShowImage.ashx?imgid=" + img.id;` when changed to `imglink.ImageUrl = "/Images/MyImage.png";` it works ? (The section in which you are trying to add controls to content template dynamically)

Comment: @HarshBaid yes that's what i mean.

Comment: @TimMedora thanks for trying to help. i appreciate it. i have kind of given up on this for now as i was creating a website for class project, and i have already submitted it. i really dont know what is wrong with it. if you have time and would like to look at source code the website is here https://github.com/btevfik/Fuddle. you can look at UserProfile.aspx, that's where the problem happens.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Asynchronous post back trigger of update panel
here is the example:

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="" EventName=""/>
```

where 'controlID' is a id of element which can cause the postback and 'eventname' is the particular event that is fired by defined control to cause postback

Answer (score 1):

Add another update panel and put your image tag into this update panel and then set property "updatemode" to "always".

try this one it will solve your problem for sure. if doesn't let me know.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion,

> You should try to add controls to the body instead of updating the `ContentTemplate` of the `UpdatePanel` i.e. Create a `Panel` control in ContentTemplate and add everything in that and update anything in that `Panel` not the `ContentTemplate`.

Check the logic and aspx syntax which shows to add controls to `Panel` which is contained in the `UpdatePanel > ContentTemplate`

**ASPX**

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="RecentUpload" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="loaduploads"/>
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlMyDynamicContent" runat="server">
                 <asp:Button CssClass="uploadButton" ID="loaduploads" runat="server" Text="Load More" OnClick="loaduploads_Click" />
            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Code Behind**

```
    ad_index += 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < upload_index; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            SSImage img = images[i];
            HyperLink imglink = new HyperLink();
            imglink.NavigateUrl = "/Image.aspx?id=" + img.id;
            imglink.ImageUrl = "/ShowImage.ashx?imgid=" + img.id;
            imglink.ToolTip = img.title;
            imglink.CssClass = "imgupload";

            // Commented old code
            //Control contentpanel = RecentUpload.ContentTemplateContainer;
            //contentpanel.Controls.AddAt(contentpanel.Controls.Count - 2, imglink);

            //Add controls to Panel instead of updating the ContentTemplate itself
            pnlMyDynamicContent.Controls.AddAt(pnlMyDynamicContent.Controls.Count - 2, imglink);
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            loaduploads.Visible = false;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have actually done that originally, but it had the same result.